# Как писать «высоко(?)образованный»?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать слово «высокообразованный» — слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Высокообразованный" пишется слитно, как и все прилагательные, образованные от наречия и существительного.
Примеры: *высокоточный, далекоидущий, близлежащий*.
Также слитно пишутся сложные прилагательные, образованные двумя существительными.
Примеры: *теплоходный, самолетный*.
Через дефис прилагательные пишутся, если обозначают:
-Оттенки цвета.
Примеры: *черно-белый, бледно-розовый.*
-Оттенки качества.
Примеры: *кисло-сладкий, квадратно-гнездовой*.
-Однородные прилагательные.
Примеры: *юго-западный, англо-русский*.
-С окончанием на -ико.
Примеры: *химико-биологический*.

Answer (score -1):

Может писаться и раздельно: наречие + прилагательное.

Comment: Высокообразованный - всегда слитно.